# How to download a game twice with an apple ID?

Tags: ios-appstore

Could you pls inform me How I could download a game twice with my apple ID on my Iphone, since I deleted it by mistake and now I can not download it.

Comment: You can search for the game in the store again, click the little cloud in the appstore and it will download again. If not, please add a screenshot or describe the problem you are running into in more detail.

Comment: What exact words are shown next to the app in the App Store? What led you to conclude "I can not download it"?

Answer (score 2):

Anything you buy on the App Store is able to be downloaded again as many times as you like, it's not like it used to be on iTunes where you downloaded it once, and then couldn't do it again if you lost the file.

To do this, just go back to the app store, and search for the app in question.  Instead of listing a price, or saying `FREE` etc, you should have a little icon showing a cloud and an arrow which you can tap to redownload.  Note, you can only download the latest version of the App, so it it has been updated since you last used it, then you cannot go back to an older version (unless you have a local backup of the file on your iTunes machine).  Also, you must be logged into the store using the same Apple ID that was used to make the original purchase.

The only way I know of that you cannot use this method, is if the app is no longer available on the App Store, in which case you can still get it, but you need to go through your *purchase history* to get to the download link instead of getting it from searching the store.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of searching for the app, you could open the **Purchased list** and download it from there.

Comment: Damn the autocorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can reinstall purchased apps (and free apps just the same) using the **App Store** app.

- On your device, navigate to the **App Store** Select the right-most
  tab, **Updates**
- At the top of this view is an area labeled
  **Purchases**. Tap on it
- This shows anything you have purchased on the Apple ID you are logged into (more on how to change that in a
  second)
- You can **Search...** for your app, or if you can't recall
  the name, tap **Not on this iPhone** to look for apps that you own,
  but are not installed on your device.
- Once you've found it, there
  should be a **Cloud icon with a Down Arrow**. Tap that and your
  download will begin!

To change your Apple ID:

- Head over to **Settings** ->**iTunes and App Store** -> **AppleID:*email@address.com*** -> **Sign Out**

See attached images for examples of navigating the App store.

[image: Step 1: Get to the Updates Page]
[image: Step 2: Tap the Purchased tab, now find the app you want!]